Why isn't my email interpreting my code and displaying the raw code?
I want to send an email with Laravel, for that, no problem, the email is sent. However, the email I want to send includes two tables that I want to show to the user. Once the email is received, half of it is “illegible”. Only the first table is interpreted, the second is shown in its raw form.
Here is my blade view.
<!-- resources/views/emails/visite/answer.blade.php -->
@component('mail::message')

@lang('Hello'),<br/><br/>

Votre demande de visite planifiée datant du {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($planif->created_at)) }} a été @if($planif->etat == 1) acceptée. @else refusée. @endif

@if($planif->etat == 1)
    @component('mail::table')
    | Nom       | Prénom    | Société     |
    |-----------|-----------|-------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_visiteurs) as $item)
    | {{ $item->name }} | {{ $item->firstname }} | {{ $item->societe }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent

    <br/><br/>

    @component('mail::table')
    | Modèle        | Immatriculation  |
    |---------------|------------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_vehicules) as $item)
    | @if($item->modele != null) {{ $item->modele }} @else Non renseigné @endif | {{ $item->immat }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent
@endif

Pour plus d'informations, veuillez contacter l'ASIP.

@lang('Sincerely yours')<br>
EamusCork
@endcomponent


Here is the function that sends the email.
public function accept_planif(Request $request, $id){
        $planif = PlanificationVisite::findOrFail($id);

        $vis_final = [];
        if($request->input('vis')){
            $vis = json_decode($request->input('vis')[0]);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($vis); $i++){
                $vis_final[] = [
                    'name' => $vis[$i]->name,
                    'firstname' => $vis[$i]->firstname,
                    'societe' => $vis[$i]->societe,
                    'document' => $vis[$i]->document
                ];
            }
        }

        $veh_final = [];
        if($request->input('veh')){
            $veh = json_decode($request->input('veh')[0]);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($veh); $i++){
                $veh_final[] = [
                    'grise' => $veh[0]->grise,
                    'immat' => $veh[0]->immat,
                    'modele' => $veh[0]->modele,
                ];
            }
        }

        $planif->update(['final_visiteurs' => json_encode($vis_final), 'final_vehicules' => json_encode($veh_final), 'etat' => 1]);

        $email = new AnswerPlanificationVisite($planif);
        Mail::to($planif->email_sent)->locale('fr')->send($email);

        return redirect()->route('visite.see_planif');
    }

This is how the email is rendered.

I tried to modify the blade view directly using the <table>, <thead>, <tbody>... tags without success. As you can see, the components don't work any better. I checked the documentation for the use of "\Mail", I don't think I made an error on the sending function and I use markdown correctly.
Here is the source code of the email.
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- resources/views/emails/visite/answer.blade.php -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light">
<style>
@media  only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.inner-body {
width: 100% !important;
}

.footer {
width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media  only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.button {
width: 100% !important;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #ffffff; color: #718096; height: 100%; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;"><img width="1" height="1" src='https://eciaccf.r.af.d.sendibt2.com/tr/op/OMollFTSRvBkb0jY8o-Ta5M0ZXU2U9xek8HU1_4aS2kfcplPBady8fOFepn-GeSkXsf7hUonWZMug_rFnjHlQBu7NcwO_S_3A992F6GQmP1NeVR-G6ToB15anoIFSHE-_gBX-1rmRA3EIII1xqORV1l3ZQFVzehDUlJv_Z1IGwvr7kDrFCUoOFfziW8kw2QVNVens6HQdhnjuR0cD_vbGD7HTXp_' />

<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; background-color: #edf2f7; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td class="header" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://eciaccf.r.af.d.sendibt2.com/tr/cl/y4U0BaZi9-XI2z1JSr3N1odchSxYa4dWK4m8d9ekqrnzcfXJjkffCBTaq7vudG9jtBGlux8ZSQGnuEMI8ubBrSTJsxR4zuwTpfwrsGmBEY0RJd4zeSTiW2vkyFXUOYf-q5nVcX8cIBCgFDTM3D6IgrpDRXCcZxyXJAuDGhmc7MF0U6ZsvyDf58PtE9CBU1m6rNzqbTqhhmtuJarYLMWdbBA3VWL2C4cyqwn2AsnAYaI6BHRJV2AgDU1TIjlQ6talXhgQ0n8Xm7dqzR9kqQ" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #3d4852; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">
EamusCork - Alerte
</a><br>
<span class="text-sm" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 10px;">Ne pas répondre à cet e-mail</span>
</td>
</tr>

<!-- Email Body -->
<tr>
<td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; background-color: #edf2f7; border-bottom: 1px solid #edf2f7; border-top: 1px solid #edf2f7; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
<table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px; background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #e8e5ef; border-radius: 2px; border-width: 1px; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.025), 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.015); margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px;">
<!-- Body content -->
<tr>
<td class="content-cell" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; max-width: 100vw; padding: 32px;">
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Bonjour,<br><br></p>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Votre demande de visite planifiée datant du 21/05/2024 a été  acceptée.
</p>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;"><strong style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">Visiteurs concernés</strong></p>
<table class="table" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<thead style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<tr>
<th style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff2; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 8px;">Nom</th>
<th style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff2; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 8px;">Prénom</th>
<th style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff2; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 8px;">Société</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Smee</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Cédric</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Eamus Cork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Ditacroute</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Thomas</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Eamus Cork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Ben Arfa</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Karim</td>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #74787e; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;">Eamus Cork</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<pre style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;"><code>&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Véhicules concernés&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;table class="table"&gt;
    &lt;thead&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;th&gt;Modèle&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;th&gt;Immatriculation&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
    &lt;/thead&gt;
    &lt;tbody&gt;
                        &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td&gt; Ford Transit &lt;/td&gt;
                &lt;td&gt;AB-123-CD&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
                        &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td&gt; Ford Transit &lt;/td&gt;
                &lt;td&gt;AB-123-CD&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
                        &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;td&gt; Ford Transit &lt;/td&gt;
                &lt;td&gt;AB-123-CD&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
                &lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
</code></pre>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Pour plus d'informations, veuillez contacter l'ASIP.</p>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Cordialement<br>
EamusCork</p>



</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 570px;">
<tr>
<td class="content-cell" align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; max-width: 100vw; padding: 32px;">
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; color: #b0adc5; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"><i style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">Article L612-14 du CSI : L'autorisation d'exercice ne confère aucune prérogative de puissance publique à l'entreprise ou aux personnes qui en bénéficient.</i><br>
© 2024 DEVS - Portail Agent. All rights reserved.</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>


In the source code, this is what happens when the display is no longer interpreted.
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<pre style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;"><code>&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Véhicules concernés&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;table class="table"&gt;

We can see the <code> tag. How to fix it ?

I think everything is filled in, the blade view, the PHP function, the mail rendering and the mail source code.

I don't know much about blade, but I think this is going to come down to the line that starts with: | @if($item->modele != null). Markdown is very sensitive to whitespace. Can you break the if into multiple lines, and then have | {{ $item->modele }} instead, making sure to keep that indentation at the same level as the table itself?

You were right, thank you. Can you write what you told me as an "answer" to highlight your solution.

I would prefer that it is the one who pointed out the error to me who posts the answer.

if the code is not interpreted here's some suggestion wrap the code into {!! HTML code here!!}.

@Romain, I'm fine with you posting what worked as an answer. I won't have capacity to get to anything any time soon.

To fix this error, it is important to check for spaces and indentations. Markdown is very sensitive to these elements, if one of the two is not used correctly then all the rest of the code is not interpreted.

I don't know much about blade, but I think this is going to come down to the line that starts with: | @if($item->modele != null). Markdown is very sensitive to whitespace. Can you break the if into multiple lines, and then have | {{ $item->modele }} instead, making sure to keep that indentation at the same level as the table itself?

@Chris Haas
Here is my code before changes :
<!-- resources/views/emails/visite/answer.blade.php -->
@component('mail::message')

@lang('Hello'),<br/><br/>

Votre demande de visite planifiée datant du {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($planif->created_at)) }} a été @if($planif->etat == 1) acceptée. @else refusée. @endif

@if($planif->etat == 1)
    @component('mail::table')
    | Nom       | Prénom    | Société     |
    |-----------|-----------|-------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_visiteurs) as $item)
    | {{ $item->name }} | {{ $item->firstname }} | {{ $item->societe }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent

    <br/><br/>

    @component('mail::table')
    | Modèle        | Immatriculation  |
    |---------------|------------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_vehicules) as $item)
    | @if($item->modele != null) {{ $item->modele }} @else Non renseigné @endif | {{ $item->immat }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent
@endif

Pour plus d'informations, veuillez contacter l'ASIP.

@lang('Sincerely yours')<br>
EamusCork
@endcomponent

And my code now :
<!-- resources/views/emails/visite/answer.blade.php -->
@component('mail::message')

@lang('Hello'),<br/><br/>

Votre demande de visite planifiée datant du {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($planif->created_at)) }} a été @if($planif->etat == 1) acceptée. @else refusée. @endif

@if($planif->etat == 1)
    @component('mail::table')
    | Nom       | Prénom    | Société     |
    |-----------|-----------|-------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_visiteurs) as $item)
    | {{ $item->name }} | {{ $item->firstname }} | {{ $item->societe }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent
    <br/><br/>
    @component('mail::table')
    | Modèle        | Immatriculation  |
    |---------------|------------------|
    @foreach(json_decode($planif->final_vehicules) as $item)
    @if($item->modele != null) | {{ $item->modele }} @else | Non renseigné @endif | {{ $item->immat }} |
    @endforeach
    @endcomponent
    <br/><br/>
@endif

Pour plus d'informations, veuillez contacter l'ASIP.

@lang('Sincerely yours')<br>
EamusCork
@endcomponent

You can see a slight change in the condition of the second table. This small error was enough to cause this raw code display error.
